# How to restart deluged daemon on macos?

Tags: mac-osx, process, daemon, bittorrent

I am running an old macbook pro as a server and have deluged running on it.

How can I restart the daemon without having to restart my server each time?

Answer (score 0):

On macOS, you will generally create a `launchd` configuration for a services - see deluge docs https://deluge.readthedocs.io/en/deluge-2.0.4/how-to/launchd-service.html

Pasted here:

> Create the file `/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.deluge-torrent.deluged.plist` containing the following:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
> <plist version="1.0">
> <dict>
>     <key>Label</key>
>     <string>org.deluge-torrent.deluged</string>
>     <key>ProgramArguments</key>
>     <array>
>         <string>/usr/local/bin/deluged</string>
>         <string>-d</string>
>         <string>-L</string>
>         <string>error</string>
>         <string>-l</string>
>         <string>/var/log/deluged.log</string>
>     </array>
>     <key>StandardOutPath</key>
>     <string>/tmp/deluged.stdout</string>
>     <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
>     <string>/tmp/deluged.stderr</string>
>     <!-- To enable running as 'deluge' user remove comments.
>     <key>UserName</key>
>     <string>deluge</string>
>     -->
>     <key>RunAtLoad</key>
>     <true/>
>     <key>KeepAlive</key>
>     <true/>
> </dict>
> </plist>
> ```
>
> Set the service to load on startup, and then start it:
>
> ```
> sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.deluge-torrent.deluged.plist
> sudo launchctl start org.deluge-torrent.deluged
> ```

You can then restart the service while running with `sudo launchctl stop` and `start`.

Note docs recommend (optionally) creating a new user `deluge` for which to use this service. You'll have to edit the above depending on whether you create a deluge user or not.